# PHP. Получить из массива значения с определенным тегом

Tags: php, orm

Я получаю из базы данных таблицу представленную в массиве. В таблице есть секции, которые кончаются на _ru, _en.

Соответственно, массив выглядит приблизительно так:

```
[
    'title_ru'  => 'текст на русском',
    'title_en'  => 'english text'
];
```

Мне необходимо написать функцию, входящий параметр которой является префиксом "_ru", либо же "_en". Каким способом это можно реализовать? То есть при запросе тега "_en" выводить только title_en?

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить с помощью функции

> stristr()

```
[
    'title_ru'  => 'текст на русском',
    'title_en'  => 'english text'
];

foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
  if(stristr($key, '_ru')) {
    $colum[] = $key;
  }
}
```

В результате в новый массив записываются только данные с нужным тегом.